# call method when entering state using Qt state machine and pyside

Tags: python, qt, methods, state, pyside

I am trying to call a method in python when entering states using Qt's state machine framework. I am able to set up the state machine and edit GUI properties, but not call methods I have written. Is there a way to do this?

Keep in mind that I am new to both Qt and Python so an example or detailed explanation would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One the best reasons for using the Qt toolkit is its superb documentation. Although it's written primarily for the C++ language, you hardly need to know C++ at all to be able to use it.

So I would suggest you start by looking through [The State Machine Framework](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/statemachine-api.html) overview.

For PySide example code (which is ported from Qt's C++ examples), take a look at the [pyside-examples repository](https://qt.gitorious.org/pyside/pyside-examples/trees/master/examples). The `animation`, `hyper-ui` and `state-machine` directories all contain several demo applications which use the state machine framework.